# MacBook 2006 install failure

Tags: uefi, macbook

I have recently upgraded an old MacBook 2006, added RAM to the maximum allowed, and replaced the original HDD with an SSD.

I want to boot any Linux system on it, as the only OS.

I have tried numerous times but failed. I have tried several versions of Linux, both from CD and on USB, and reFIT does not seem to want to allow me to start the install.

Comment: *does not seem to want to allow me to start the install*; the computer doesn't recognize a live boot or it doesn't let you install from a live session? What images have you tried? Maybe it's worth testing whether an older release will work.

Comment: Also, since reFit is depreciated, you may wish instead to use reFind https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/ http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Comment: You should also check if the problem is not the Drive. You can do that by trying even a Windows OS and seeing if it works or by testing the drive in any other way. This is just to make sure that the newly replaced SSD is working well with the MacBook.